# OAuth. Twitter. StatusCode: 403. SSL is required. C#

Tags: c#, ssl, twitter, oauth, windows-phone-8.1

I need your help!

My code:

```
 string twitterRequestTokenUrl = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";


HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    string data = "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + oauth_consumer_key +
                   "\", oauth_nonce=\"" + oauth_nonce +
                   "\", oauth_signature=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature) +
                   "\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"" + oauth_timestamp +
                   "\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"";
    request.Headers.Authorization = new       System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth", data);
    request.RequestUri = new Uri(twitterRequestTokenUrl, UriKind.Absolute);

    request.Method = new HttpMethod("POST");    
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

What could be the problem, I send an inquiry:

> request   {Method: POST, RequestUri:
>   'http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   , Headers: {   Authorization: OAuth
>   oauth_consumer_key="*******************",
>   oauth_nonce="NjM1NjQwOTY0MzAzMjMwNjgw",
>   oauth_signature="nIQIuJqRLP2naUxgC0cTHqFqUkc%3D",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1428485230",
>   oauth_version="1.0" }}    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage

and get the following answer:

> StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { connection: close date: Wed,
>   08 Apr 2015 09:06:50 GMT server: tsa_b set-cookie:
>   guest_id=v1%3A142848401049508299; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/;
>   Expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2017 09:06:50 UTC x-connection-hash:
>   407806cc38f466361aa7e9efb2a35601 x-response-time: 5 Content-Length: 16
>   content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 } SSL is required

Comment: Try changing your `twitterRequestTokenUrl` to use "https" instead of http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing

```
string twitterRequestTokenUrl = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
```

to

```
string twitterRequestTokenUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
```

should solve your issue.

The reason you are seeing a status code of 403 is since "[only SSL connections are allowed in Twitter API endpoints](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/ssl)"